# Significado de "determinar" en Colombia

Tags: uso-de-palabras, colombia

¿Qué significa *determinar* en un contexto social, en Colombia y quizá en paises de Centroamérica?

El [diccionario](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/definicion.php?palabra=determinar&lema=no) no dice nada al respecto.

Ejemplo:

> Ella no me determina.

Comment: ¿Puedes darnos el contexto?

Comment: @Spreadsheet Un amigo panameño dijo "la niña ya no me determina". La canción de Grupo Niche dice "Si no me determinan, desconozco". Así, he oido varias veces "determinar" en contextos sociales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Determina`en el caso de Colombia puede significar varias cosas.

En el caso de tu ejemplo significa que Ella no le da órdenes al locutor. En el sentido en que determinar es definir algo de alguna manera. De definir algo, en ese sentido es una personalización "forzada"

Determinar se puede entender como una orden hacia un objeto o una persona.

> Él determinó que el carro aún no estaba en buenas condiciones.
>
> Él le determinó su orden del día.

En centroamérica no conozco mucho de los sentidos que se puedan entender. Si alguien puede mejorar la respuesta que no dude en hacerlo.

Comment: Lamento estar en desacuerdo; la expresión "no me determina", usada en el contesto en que pregunta Jorge Campos, significa "me ignora" tal como lo ha dicho Luferquisa en [su respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4035/157). Otra cosa son las acepciones del verbo determinar, pero "no me determina" es una frase hecha, con el significado antes mencionado.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Entiendo lo que dices. Pero la verdad nunca lo había escuchado como "me ignora" pero es interesante. Si quieres edita la respuesta. Es la primera vez que escucho que determinar podría tener tal acepción. Gracias en todo caso.

Comment: No. Yo no suelo editar respuestas ajenas para hacer cambios mayores (yo sé que se puede hacer y que, de hecho, es parte de la filosofía de estos sitios, pero no me gusta hacerlo).

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con Gustavo. El ejemplo significa. "me ignora"

Answer (score 4):

En el caso puntual que señalas: "Ella no me determina", se refiere a que ella no se da cuenta que existo, no me habla, no me mira.
Es como decir: "Ella me ignora".

En otros contextos se aplicaría la respuesta anterior.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se trata de usos localizados, aunque es cierto que el DRAE recoge muchos de ellos, suele esperar a que tales lleguen a tener un uso bastante extenso (al menos en la última actualización, era casi el criterio con más peso: el número de países en que disfruta de uso)

Para los demás usos y términos, ASALE tiene un excelente [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/). En él, topamos la siguiente entrada saliente de Honduras, Panamá y Colombia:

> **determinar**
>
> **I.1.tr.** *Ho, Pa, Co.* Prestar atención de forma patente a una persona

Tal acepción encaja bien con el ejemplo proveído: *ella no me determina* se podría decir en un lenguaje panhispánico *ella no me presta atención* o *ella no me hace caso*.

Comment: Me descubres el participio _proveído_, pensaba que solo existía _provisto_.